# Python/Pandas - How to amend my ARIMA code actually forecast after training/testing done

Tags: python, pandas, forecasting, arima

My dataset looks like this:

```
date           bookings
2017-01-01     438
2017-01-02     167
...
2017-12-31     45
2018-01-01     748
...
2018-11-29     223
```

I need something like this (i.e. forecasted data beyond dataset):

```
date           bookings
2017-01-01     438
2017-01-02     167
...
2017-12-31     45
2018-01-01     748
...
2018-11-29     223
2018-11-30     98
...
2018-12-30     73
2018-12-31     100
```

Code used thus far (training/test phase):

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
# from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
# from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 14
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12
matplotlib.rcParams['text.color'] = 'k'

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',names = ["date","bookings"],index_col=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

X = df.values
size = int(len(X) * 0.66)
train, test = X[0:size], X[size:len(X)]
history = [x for x in train]
predictions = list()
for t in range(len(test)): 
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(1,1,0))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
    output = model_fit.forecast()

    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat) 

    obs = test[t]
    history.append(obs)

    #   print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))
#error = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
#print(error)
#print('Test MSE: %.3f' % error)
# plot
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 8))
plt.plot(test)
plt.plot(predictions, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Exported results to csv:

```
df_forecast = pd.DataFrame(predictions)
df_test = pd.DataFrame(test)
result = pd.merge(df_test, df_forecast, left_index=True, right_index=True)
result.rename(columns = {'0_x': 'Test', '0_y': 'Forecast'}, inplace=True)
```

Trouble I'm having is using the model to generate forecasts beyond my dataset. How do I amend the code for it to do what it's trained to do, which is generate forecasts? I kind of understand that I need to extend the iteration until a certain end date but when doing so I get wack results...

How do I go from what I have to creating predictions (not tests) which can then be exported to a csv?

What I tried to do (and failed):

```
# APPLICATION PHASE ATTEMPT
fc_size =  len(pd.date_range(start='29/11/2018', end='31/12/2018'))

for i in range(fc_size):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(1,1,0))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
    output = model_fit.forecast()
    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    obs = predictions[t]
    history.append(obs)
#   print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))
# error = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
# print('Test MSE: %.3f' % error)

# plot
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 8))
plt.plot(test)
plt.plot(predictions, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Source I used: https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I kind of understand that I need to extend the iteration until a certain end date but when doing so I get wack results." ?

Comment: @AlexKinman - Essentially in the final block of code under "What I tried to do", this was my attempt at extending the iteration within the for loop range in hopes of getting future forecasts but the plot showing a horizontal straight line

Comment: I meant what are the results? Why do you say they are 'wack' Can you plot them or provide the data? I ask because sometimes ARIMA gives seemingly bad results (e.g. a flat forecast) but that is actually the best result possible given the data.